# Like box - Min Height? / Exact Url

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

Quick couple of questions just to clarify the likebox setup - Does the Likebox have a min height without Faces?

Secondly -  does the url need to be presice as in

```
 https://www.facebook.com/ConistonBoatingCentre
```

rather than

```
 https://www.facebook.com/ConistonBoatingCentre?fref=ts
```

or does it not matter - just because it doesn't make it clear on the form and I need to send the code over to a large client and want to make sure its foolproof!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## Ofcourse it Wont Work!!

check it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Answer (score 0):

23 pixels is the height without faces.